# "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" when I can see the objects exist

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Just trying to get some rows out of a database and loop through but I am get the non-object error.

```
    $db = classes_pdoDB::getConnection();
    $query = "SELECT *
              FROM lesson
              WHERE userID=:userID";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(':userID' => $userID));
    $lessons = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach ($lessons as $lesson){

        print_r ($lesson);

        $page->addToBody ("<div class=\"editLessonEntry\">
            <p><a href=\"editLesson.php?lessonid=" . $lesson->lessonID . "\" >" . $lesson->lessonTitle . "</a></p>
            <p>" . $lesson->lessonSummary . " </p>
        </div>
        <hr />");

    }
```

Not really certain what the error is because the print_r is working fine and showing me all the objects which I am trying to include. I'm sure like all of my questions I am just overlooking something incredibly simple. But I really cannot see it. I have other similar functions through the site which work fine and I can't see the differences really.

Comment: Why are you running a loop for each lesson and returning immediately ? Also provide the error dump. Is it on line "return $less..." ?

Comment: 1) Why are you calling `return` in the loop? `return $lesson->lessonID;`  2) Have you defined  `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` to return objects? If not, it will be returning arrays.

Comment: What line is the error? also, could it be that the result set is empty?

Comment: Post example output of the `print_r()`. I'll bet anything it's an array and not an object. What you need to be using is `$lesson['lessonSummary']`, `$lesson['lessonID']`

Comment: sorry I left that "return $lesson.." in but I have editted to what I was using to debug, I was just testing before. The errors are coming every time I am calling $lesson->[something]. I know the loop is working because the rest of the html is appearing.

I havent defined `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` but other similar functions work without it. Would I define it with `self::$dbConnection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE );` in my PDO class?

Comment: @Michael - `Array ( [lessonID] => 11 [0] => 11 [lessonTitle] => Forms [1] => Forms [lessonSummary] => lesson on forms in html [2] => lesson on forms in html [verified] => N [3] => N [votes] => 1 [4] => 1 [userID] => 15 [5] => 15 [date] => 2012-03-25 05:05:07 [6] => 2012-03-25 05:05:07 [type] => [7] => [module] => [8] => [school] => Markup [9] => Markup [class] => HTML [10] => HTML ) `

I can see that you are probably right, I usually use `fetchObject` I didn't realise. I didn't know that `fetchAll` did not return an array of objects

Comment: @Richie Ok, thought so. I put it in as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchAll()` returns an array unless you have specified the class to return with `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`.  So in this case, you should be accessing `$lesson` by array elements rather than object properties:

```
$lessons = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($lessons as $lesson){

    print_r ($lesson);

    $page->addToBody ("<div class=\"editLessonEntry\">
        <p><a href=\"editLesson.php?lessonid=" . $lesson['lessonID'] . "\" >" . $lesson['lessonTitle'] . "</a></p>
        <p>" . $lesson['lessonSummary'] . " </p>
    </div>
    <hr />");
 }
```

If you must get these as an object and have a `Lesson` class, you can do it this way:

```
$lessons = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Lesson");
```

This assumes the `Lesson` class takes no parameters to its constructor.  This is detailed in the [`fetchAll()` documentation.](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchall.php)